# Error using actions-on-google Carousel or List with dialogflow's WebhookClient

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I tried everything to get [this](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/blob/master/samples/actions-on-google/functions/index.js) example working (In particular the Carousel part). Every time I try to use List or Suggestions or Carousel from actions on google, it gives me in the google simulator this error:
[error from actions on google simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I7sH.png)

Here's the Intent code from my heroku webhook (it's copy paste from the example)

```
function prova(agent){
let conv = agent.conv();
const imageUrl = 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png';
const imageUrl2 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw';
const linkUrl = 'https://assistant.google.com/';

conv.ask(new Carousel({
  title: 'Google Assistant',
  items: {
    'WorksWithGoogleAssistantItemKey': {
      title: 'Works With the Google Assistant',
      description: 'If you see this logo, you know it will work with the Google Assistant.',
      image: {
        url: imageUrl,
        accessibilityText: 'Works With the Google Assistant logo',
      },
    },
    'GoogleHomeItemKey': {
      title: 'Google Home',
      description: 'Google Home is a powerful speaker and voice Assistant.',
      image: {
        url: imageUrl2,
        accessibilityText: 'Google Home'
      },
    },
  },
}));
agent.add(conv);
}
```

So, here's my dependencies:

[package.json dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhQfS.png)

Anyone who has already solved this issue? I didn't find anything on this...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your implementation you missed a line from the original example. You need to have a `SimpleResponse` before your carousel. So you would need a line such as

```
conv.ask('Please choose an item:');
```

on the line before the `conv.ask()` for the `new Carousel`.

Comment: Easy enough to miss, and hopefully will help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the JSON payload for Carousel directly like this:

```
function prova(agent){
    const imageUrl = 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png';
    const imageUrl2 = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw';
    const linkUrl = 'https://assistant.google.com/';

    agent.add(new Payload(agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE,   {
        "expectUserResponse": true,
        "richResponse": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "simpleResponse": {
                        "textToSpeech": "Please choose an item:"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "systemIntent": {
            "intent": "actions.intent.OPTION",
            "data": {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.OptionValueSpec",
                "carouselSelect": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "optionInfo": {
                                "key": "WorksWithGoogleAssistantItemKey"
                            },
                            "description": "If you see this logo, you know it will work with the Google Assistant.",
                            "image": {
                                "url": imageUrl,
                                "accessibilityText": "Works With the Google Assistant logo"
                            },
                            "title": "Works With the Google Assistant"
                        },
                        {
                            "optionInfo": {
                                "key": "GoogleHomeItemKey"
                            },
                            "description": "Google Home is a powerful speaker and voice Assistant.",
                            "image": {
                                "url": imageUrl2,
                                "accessibilityText": "Google Home"
                            },
                            "title": "Google Home"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

Result:
[image]